# Sql clause is rollback before integration test ended

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spock, jooq

I have a problem and after two days of research, I was not able to find a solution. I have a simple app so far just read all data from table and wanted to write an integration test for it.

Here is my test:

```
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("integrationTest")
class StockFacadeIT extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    StockFacadeImpl stockFacade

    @Autowired
    DSLContext dslContext

    @Sql(scripts = "/add_sample_stocks.sql")
    def 'should return list of ticker in correct order'() {
        when:
        def tickers = stockFacade.loadAllTickers(dslContext)
        println "when cluase"

        then:
        println "then cluase"
        tickers.getAt(0) == 'abc'
        tickers.getAt(1) == 'gpw'
        tickers.getAt(2) == 'kgh'
        tickers.getAt(3) == 'tpe'
    }
}
```

In log I see:

```
2017-11-06 21:30:09.478  INFO 21124 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@6a01e23 testClass = StockFacadeIT, testInstance = com.gpw.radar.stock.StockFacadeIT@455cbf18, testMethod = $spock_feature_0_0@StockFacadeIT, [...] rollback [true]
2017-11-06 21:30:09.478  INFO 21124 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [add_sample_stocks.sql]
2017-11-06 21:30:09.478  INFO 21124 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [add_sample_stocks.sql] in 0 ms.
2017-11-06 21:30:09.712  INFO 21124 --- [           main] org.jooq.Constants                       :
when cluase
then cluase
2017-11-06 21:30:09.869  INFO 21124 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@6a01e23 testClass = StockFacadeIT, testInstance = com.gpw.radar.stock.StockFacadeIT@455cbf18, testMethod = $spock_feature_0_0@StockFacadeIT, testException = Condition not satisfied:
```

So from log perspective I see that transaction begin before test and rolback is run after test ("then clause"). But test doesn't pass beacuase database is empty. When I delete the @Transactional annotation, it passed but inserted records stayed at DB. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sometimes it is necessary to flush the transaction for values to show up.

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem was. As I added spring framework after jooq. My final configuration for jooq looks like:

```
@Bean
    @Profile("integrationTest")
    public DSLContext TestDslContext(DataSource dataSource) {
        return DSL.using(new DefaultConfiguration()
                .set(dataSource)
                .set(new Settings().withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.AS_IS))
                .set(SQLDialect.H2)
                .set(getRecordMapperProvider())
        );
    }
```

So when I remove this part and use auto config of spring boot the transactions works, however, I have checked how DSLContext config looks when is created by spring I have TransactionProvider and ExecuteListenerProvider missing. When I inject it and set to my custom config the transactions still does not work.